# Based on CKM matrix, shouldn't bottom lifetime be longer than strange lifetime?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quarks

When discussing the CKM matrix, my professor mentioned that the stability of the bottom quark could be attributed to the very high probability amplitude for $b\to t$ transformation, which is kinematically forbidden (unless the bottom quark is accelerated to have sufficient mass, which while in a bound state is not exactly possible). This seems logical enough. Simply because the amplitudes of $b\to c$ and $b\to u$ are small, it takes longer for those decay modes to occur, manifesting in bottom quark stability.

However, when reading Wikipedia, I noticed that strange quark lifetime is actually longer than bottom quark lifetime ($10^{-8}-10^{-10}$ s versus $10^{-12}$ s). This seems slightly counter-intuitive to me because looking at the decay modes, while $s\to t$ and $s\to c$ are kinematically forbidden, $s\to u$ is still allowed with amplitude of roughly, $v_{us}=0.225$, such that probability of transition is $|v_{us}|^2=0.05$. Comparing this to the bottom quark decays, $b\to c$, and $b\to u$, which have, $|v_{cb}|^2=0.001$, and $|v_{ub}|^2=0.00001$, such that the net probability for either decay is $0.00101$, we find that in theory, bottom lifetime should be longer, because alternate decay modes are more suppressed than alternate strange decay to $s\to u$.

Why is the strange quark still more stable than the bottom quark? What factors contribute to this discrepancy?

Comment: Look at [Fermi's Golden rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule). Matrix elements are only one of two factors that go into transition rates. How does the other one compare between b-decays and s-decays?

Comment: Ah, I see. So the true transition rate is not only a result of the dynamics encoded in the matrix element, but also the available phase space, which I've neglected?